# How to install drupal 8.5.0 using composer?

Tags: drupal-8

I am trying to install Drupal 8.5.0 via composer, using drupal-composer/drupal-project.

My OS is windows and I have run the command on "Command Prompt"

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction
```

After run this command I got `drupal 8.7.4`.

But I want to install drupal 8.5.0 via composer for some demo purpose.

Please suggest me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you tried to run will download the latest dev version of the project. If you want to modify versions, or anything that comes along with the project, you can do so by adding the `--no-install` flag to your command:

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev some-dir --stability dev --no-interaction --no-install
```

This will download the files, but won't run `composer install`. Now you can edit the composer.json file to change the desired version of the `drupal/core` package.

But sadly whis will make conflicts with the `webflo/drupal-core-require-dev` package which only accepts higher core version than `8.7.0` - so you need to change that line as well to the desired version.

So, the `require` and `require-dev` section of the composer.json looks like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "composer/installers": "^1.2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
    "drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold": "^2.5",
    "drupal/console": "^1.0.2",
    "drupal/core": "8.5.0",
    "drush/drush": "^9.0.0",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
    "zaporylie/composer-drupal-optimizations": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "webflo/drupal-core-require-dev": "8.5.0"
},
```

After changing the lines, all you need to do is run the command:

```
composer install
```

Also check out [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies) thread on drupal.org